# I have around 1 million documents in my database but Mongoose findOneAndUpdate is not working with nested async.each function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, async.js

Here `SerpData` is my collection-1 from which I am fetching data and inserting in `urlCollection` which my collection-2, but what is happening is, it is successfully fetching data from `serpData` collection but not storing in `urlCollection` when I am using `async.each`. It is working with `async.eachSeries` but it is taking so long as I have around 1 million docs. Any help will be appreciated.

```
model.serpData.find({},(err, rows)=>{
if(err){
  console.log(err);
}
else{
  async.each(rows,(row, callback)=>{
    async.each(row.data[0].organic,(url, innerCallback)=>{
      model.urlCollection.findOneAndUpdate({url:url.result_url},{$set:{url:url.result_url},$inc:{count:1}},{upsert: true},(err)=>{
        innerCallback(err);
      });
    },(err)=>{
      callback(err);
    });
  },(err)=>{
    console.log('all urls are collected');
  });
}
```

});

Comment: Use Promise.all

Comment: Sam, why do you think that Promise.all will help?

Comment: @Sam can you please clearify?

Comment: Why are you not calling **callback** function inside nested async.each after every succesfull **findOneAndUpdate** Only on error? BTW are you sure that there are only one record with such url?

Comment: @ByteMaster I am returning callback function inside the callback of nested async.each, err may null in this case. And I am not sure whether there is only URL, but for my use case I want first matched doc.